Healing Powers for Who?
Should all saved Christians attempt to heal as St Paul commanded?  Or is this reserved to a special group of people, assuming all are true believers?   I would hate to attempt and fail because I don't know how, like many..

1 Cor 12:8To one there is given through the Spirit the message of wisdom, to another the message of knowledge by the same Spirit, 9to another faith by the same Spirit, to another gifts of healing by that one Spirit, 10to another the working of miracles, to another prophecy, to another distinguishing between spirits, to another speaking in various tongues, and to still another the interpretation of tongues. 11All these are the work of one and the same Spirit, who apportions them to each one as He determines.

It is the Holy Spirit that decides who gets which gift and how it is used, not us.
